# Why does ADODB.connection object swallow errors?

Tags: sql-server, ado

When I create a connection to a database using the ADODB.Connection object to create a connection to a SQLServer database, I expect that when I use a throw statement I expect to have records in the `conn.Errors` collection.

Instead, if I do any of the following two, the Errors collection will be empty:

- Return any rows as a result set. This can happen if the severity of
  the error is low enough that rows are still returned to the caller
- If I succesfully insert any rows into any table somewhere in my sql
  statement, all other errors will be ignored by the ADO object.

The second scenario there is especially frustrating and I can't find any documentation to explain why this would happen, or how to avoid it.

To reproduce

```
$conn = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$conn.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI11;Initial Catalog=master;Application Name=Application;Data Source=.;DataTypeComptibility=80;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$conn.Execute('THROW 50000, ''Exceptional Exception'', 10')
```

After that sequence, calling

```
$conn.Errors.count
```

Will return `1`

However if you now run

```
$conn.Execute('CREATE TABLE #t (name varchar(256)); INSERT #t values(''name''); DROP TABLE #t ; THROW 50000, ''Sad, Ignored Exception'', 10')
```

Then calling

```
$conn.Errors.count
```

results in `0`

Is there some scenario where this behavior would be desirable? I don't understand the thinking that would have gone into making the object behave this way.

Is there a way to avoid this issue and ensure that any errors thrown in my statement are always returned to me.

As it stands right now, if there is any successfull insert in my sql statement, I can never know if some other part of the statement threw an error.

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in your script.

Comment: @DanGuzman You want to put that in an answer so I can mark it as accepted? I won't admit how hard I face palmed just now.